# ElasticSearch - Get Relevant Search Filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a query that is successful, but I am trying to render a list to the user that would show relevant filters for the users next search if they choose to search again with the same term they used previously. I have no idea how to do this though. I don't see any information about doing this either. Here is the query I have at the moment. I'm using Ruby on Rails with elasticsearch-rails gem.

```
@products = Product.search(
     query:{
       function_score:{
         query:{
           bool:{
             must:{
               multi_match:{
                 fields: ['brand^5', '_all'],
                 query: "#{query}",
                 fuzziness: "AUTO"
               }
             },
             filter: {
                term: {"brand": "NordicTrack"}

                term: {"category": "Lubricants & Cleaners"}

             }
           }
         },
         field_value_factor:{
            field: "popularity",
            modifier: "log1p"
         }
       }
     }).page(page).per(25)
```

Comment: Instead of calling the pagination methods on the result set, see if the metrics/ aggregations section of the response is available in the returned object. You can always paginate after extracting what other data is in there.